# How to perform logical AND operation by refering the coordinates in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, logical-operators

The matrix `A` contains 1's in different coordinates:

```
A =
 1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

**Step 1:**
Finding the coordinates of the 1's. For example, in the first row it is (1,1) and (1,5).

```
c1 = find(A==1)
```

**Step 2:**
Scanning this coordinates in Main `M` matrix and performing AND operation. If the answer is 1 then place the 1 in corresponding coordinates of `A` matrix. For example, `(1,1) (1,5)` in `M` matrix is ANDed with `(2,1)(2,5)==> 1 1 ANDed 0 0 ==>0 0`. Likewise `(3,1) (3,5)` upto `(10,1) (10,5)` in `M` matrix. If any place 1 it came place the 1 in respective coordinate place in `A` matrix.

```
M =
 1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
 1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
 1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
 1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1
```

Here in the given matrix in 4th row `A` matrix has 1 in (4,4) check the remaining coordinates in `M` matrix. It is ANDed with (1,4) the (2,4), while (9,4) it is 1. Place that 1 in `A` matrix (4,9). I have tried with the code but it is not working in generic case.

```
a = 1:size(M)
R1 = 1;
for j = 1:size(A)
    A1 = A(j,:)
    c = find(A1==1) % finding 1's place
    l = length(c)
    a1 = a(a~=j)
    for k = a1(1):a1(end)
        R1 = 1;
        for i = 1:l1
            temp1 = R1
            R1 = and(M(j,c(i)),M(k,c(i)))  % performing AND operations
            R2 = and(R1,temp1)
        end
        if (R2==1)     % if the condition is satisfied by 1
            A(j,k)=1   % place the 1 in the particular coordinate in A matrix
        end
    end
end
New_A = A

New_A =
 1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what are you trying to do. How do you choose what to compare between the matrices? what happens when one of the matrices is bigger than the other?

Comment: Actually picking up 1's place coordinates from A matrix. Scan particular coordinates in M matrix then perform AND operation with that. for eg Take 1st row in A matrix the places of 1's is 1 and 5.Now AND is performed in M matrix 1 and 5 th column alone.i.e (1,1)(1,5)AND(2,1)(2,5) if the ans is 1 1 means place 1 in1st row A matrix (1,2) (1,5) place of A matrix.Then is it checked with (1,1)(1,5)AND(3,1)(3,5) if the ans is 0 leave unchaged.

Comment: This matrix size doesn't matter because this operation will runs upto (size(A))times only that is 5 times in the above-given matrix.The M matrix is for checking the particular column which we picked 1'splaces with A matrix.If satisfied place the 1 in particular row which place it get satisfied with M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then for each row `r` of `A` you want to extract all `M` columns where `A(r,:)==1`, then place `1` in first column `c` of `A(r,:)` that all the columns in row `c` in the extracted `M` is 1. Using the updated `A` continue the process on the same row until you reach the end, and move to the next row.

Here is a code for that (assuming `size(A,1)==size(M,2)`):

```
new_A = A;                          % copy the current state
for r = 1:size(new_A,1)
        Mc = M(:,new_A(r,:)==1).';  % extract the relevat columns in new_A
        c = 1;                      % column counter
        while c<=size(A,2)
            next_item = find(all(Mc(:,c:end),1),1)+c-1; % find the next item to change
            new_A(r,next_item) = 1;             % if all rows in Mc are 1, then place 1
            Mc = M(:,new_A(r,:)==1).';          % extract the relevat columns in new_A
            c = c+1;                            % go to the next column
        end
end
```

which result in `new_A` using your `A` and `M` above:

```
new_A =
     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Is this what you looked for?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.But there is one problem. It has to update A matrix every time after the process. For eg while taking 4th row in A matrix 1's place is in (4,4). It has to process with (1,4) .. (10,4) in M matrix. There (9,4) has satisfied the condition. So 1 placed in (4,9) in A matrix. The updated A matrix has two 1's in 4th row that is (4,4) (4,9). Now the process has satisfy (4,4) (4,9) AND (1,4) (1,9),...(10,4)(10,9). Now all these place won't satisfy the condition. Soo, in new_A  does not have 1 in (4,10)th place.

Comment: So you want to repeat this at the row level, i.e. update the same row in `A` again and again before continue to the next row? or you want to go over the all matrix once, and after finished start over again? and **most important** -  when should this process stop?

Comment: The process should end by checking the A matrix row by row there is no other possibility to fit 1's. For eg after updating the 4th row as (4,4) (4,9) in A matrix it is checked with M matrix , is there any possibility to fit 1. If not satisfied the process end for 4th row. similarly for 5th row then stop.

Comment: For the first 3 rows in A matrix it is not satisfied for first time check itself so the process ends row by row. In some cases A might updated many times as the matrix size increases. In generic it has to check for possiblity to fit 1's with updated A matrix. If not proceed to next row the stop iterations.

Comment: I think I lost you completely... I have done another edit to the answer, my last try, this time looping over the rows until there is no further change, though I'm not sure it makes any difference. I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: But it has to come   4th row   0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0 5th row 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0.

Comment: The new edited answer doesn't gave the above mensioned answer.

Comment: I think you have a mistake here: after the first run, `A(4,:)  = 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1`, than it runs again (on three columns in M) and find no change to do. Same for `A(5,:) =  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0` after the first run, than it runs again (on 4 columns in M) and find no change to do.

Comment: That means while scanning the A matrix for first time only (4,4) is there.It has to do operation with (1,4) (2,4).. (10,4) in M matrix. There it satisfy (9,4).Once it satified it has to put it in A matrix.

Comment: Next time A's 4th row will be (4,4) (4,9). This will be operated with M matrix (1,4)(1,9).... (10,4)(10,9)... while doing (4,4)(4,9)AND(10,4)(10,9)==> 1 1 AND 1 0==> 0 So it is not satifying.

Comment: So you want to repeat the process after each element that changes, not the whole row. Right?

Comment: Well, I have edited my answer to match your description, I hope it's correct now.

Comment: Yes I got it. Now it works for all matrices.